# How do I change the default driver for the node mssql package?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    user: 'userName',
    driver : 'msnodesqlv8',
    password: 'mypassword',
    server: 'x.x.x.x', // 
    database: 'databaseName'
}
```

This is how I currently initialise the mssql connection. I want to use the msnodesqlv8 driver instead of TDS. When I run this code I keep getting error message 'Unknown driver msnodesqlv8!' What else do I need to do ? Do I perhaps need to import the msnodesqlv8 ? Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: which version of `mssql` are you using? As using the latest version from npm using your sample code for me throws `Cannot find module 'msnodesqlv8'`, meaning that the `msnodesqlv8` driver needs to be included in your package.json and installed separately.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had an outdated version of mssql. I updated it to version 2.5.0 and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have sorted this out but do have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#3x-to-4x-changes.

Currently (apr 2018), in msnodesqlv8, drivers are no longer loaded dynamically so the library is now compatible with Webpack. To use msnodesqlv8 driver, use:

> const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

Cheers,

pedro.